# How to store a result set of a ORACLE sql query?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Example : There is a table "ID_NAME" with one column "ID" which has 2000 entries like 1,2,3.. 2000.
I've have a query

> select id from ID_NAME where id < 1001;

```
> Result :  1 2 3 4 . .1000
```

My PL SQL block looks like this,

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    declare
    var1 number;
    var2 number;
    var3 number;
    var4 number;
    var5 number;
    var6 number;
    var7 number;
    var8 number;
    var9 number;
    var10 number;
    begin
    with set1 as (select id from ID_NAME where id < 1001)
    select count(*) into var1 from table1 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var2 from table2 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var3 from table3 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var4 from table4 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var5 from table5 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var6 from table6 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var7 from table7 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var8 from table8 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var9 from table9 where id in (select * from set1);
    select count(*) into var10 from table10 where id in (select * from set1);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var1||','||var2||','||var3||','||var4||','||var5||','||var6||','||var7||','||var8||','||var9||','||var10);
end;
```

but I'm getting

> PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

in my sql developer.

I want to use the SET1 from my below query so that I don't have to run it again and again in the count(*) sub queries

```
with set1 as (select id from ID_NAME where id < 1001)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    declare
    var1 number;
    var2 number;
    var3 number;
    var4 number;
    var5 number;
    var6 number;
    var7 number;
    var8 number;
    var9 number;
    var10 number;
    begin
    with set1 as (select id from ID_NAME where id < 1001)
    select 
    (select count(*) from table1 where id in (select * from set1)),
    (select count(*) from table2 where id in (select * from set1)),
    ..............
    (select count(*) from table9 where id in (select * from set1)),
    (select count(*) from table10 where id in (select * from set1))
    into var1,var2,.....,var9,var10
    from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var1||','||var2||','||var3||','||var4||','||var5||','||var6||','||var7||','||var8||','||var9||','||var10);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building a CTE so it goes like this:  For each select statement you need to join with CTE.

```
   declare
    var1 number;
    var2 number;
    var3 number;
    var4 number;
    var5 number;
    var6 number;
    var7 number;
    var8 number;
    var9 number;
    var10 number;
    begin
    with set1 as (select emp_id from employee where emp_id < 1001)
    select count(*) into var1 from employee 
    where emp_id in (select eno from emp_sal);

    with set1 as (select emp_id from employee where emp_id < 1001)
    select count(*) into var2 from employee 
    where emp_id in (select eno from emp_sal);


    .
    .
    .
    . 
    and so on
--    select count(*) into var2 from table2 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var3 from table3 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var4 from table4 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var5 from table5 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var6 from table6 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var7 from table7 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var8 from table8 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var9 from table9 where id in (select * from set1);
--    select count(*) into var10 from table10 where id in (select * from set1);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var1||','||var2||','||var3||','||var4||','||var5||','||var6||','||var7||','||var8||','||var9||','||var10);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, a `with` clause or Common Table Expression is part of a query. It doesn't set a program variable.

```
with xyz as (select blah from blahblah where something = somethingelse)
select blah from xyz;
```

You can't refer to `xyz` in other queries - it is just a clause within a single query.